# Suppose that $F \subset E^*$ is total and $E$ is reflexive. Is $F$ norming?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a separable Banach space and let $F \subset E^*$ be a subspace that is total, i.e. if $f(x) =0$ for all $f \in F$, then $x = 0$.

If $E$ is reflexive, then must this set also be norming? i.e. does

$|x|_F:= \sup \{ |f(x)| \ | \ f \in F, \; |f|=1 \}$

define a norm equivalent to $|.|$?

Comment: @DavidMitra I meant for $F$ to be a subspace, edited, thank you

Comment: It seems this is true for quasireflexive spaces $X$ (dim$(X^{**}/X)<\infty$).  You can find references [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-031-01/S0002-9939-1972-0288560-8/S0002-9939-1972-0288560-8.pdf). There may be a simple proof for the reflexive case, but I can't see it yet.

Comment: @DavidMitra Does this follow from the fact $F$ is weak star dense? Since weak star density = weak density by reflexivity, and $F$ is a closed subspace it must be all of $E^*$ (hence 1-norming).